# Ganeti and automatic failover

Tags: high-availability, cluster, drbd, ganeti

I'm building a simple 2-node cluster with Ganeti+DRBD... What is the recommended way to setup automatic failover?
I'm used to Heartbeat, but [they say](http://groups.google.com/group/ganeti/msg/8a0a58eff2b97ddf) it should be avoided with my setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIU, the message your linking just mean heartbeat should not take action on DRBD on its own as this is well managed by ganeti.
Instead, heartbeat/pacemaker could be used to detect node failure and trigger Ganeti failover sequence, i.e. gnt-* commands.